# How to get a TextMeshProUGUI component from an instantiated/cloned gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk, textmeshpro

A picture from Hierarchy :

[image: Hierarchy]

I instantiate the SlateUGUI prefab and then later tried to access the highlitged gameobject 'TextDebug' using :

```
 TextMeshProUGUI text1 = SlateInstant.transform.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
 text1.text = "This works";
```

However, it does not work :
Error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I am a bit skeptical to use `GetComponentInChildren<>()` as it can be seen from the hierarchy it is quite a lot of children and sub-children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Transform.Find` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html)

> **Note**: Find does **not** perform a **recursive** descend down a Transform hierarchy.

This means: It only find first level childs!

You would need to provide the entire path starting from the first direct child like e.g.

```
TextMeshProUGUI text1 = SlateInstant.transform.Find("Scroll View/Viewport/Content/GridLayout1/Column2/TextDebug").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
text1.text = "This works";
```

---

Way better would be to have a certain controller component on the most top parent (root) of the prefab and there have a field like e.g.

```
public class SlateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI TextDebug;
}
```

and in the prefab edit mode drag and drop the `TextDebug` object into that slot in the Inspector.

And then simply use e.g.

```
SlateInstant.GetComponent<TheControllerClass>().TextDebug.text = "XYZ";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy solution would be to add a tag to the instantiated object and then use the [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)